# Getting value after button click with BeautifulSoup Python - Scraper OLX

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape phone number from olx offer: e.g.

https://www.olx.pl/d/oferta/mieszkanie-do-wynajecia-40m2-ul-kosciuszki-96-CID3-IDNc5Bv.html#cc0c9f1b5c;promoted

This is my code:

```
raw_text = [elem for elem in soup.find_all('button')
            if 'phoneToken' in elem.text][0].text.strip()
token = re.findall(r"['\"](.*?)['\"]", raw_text)[0]
```

basic on
https://github.com/digitalashes/olx-parser/blob/master/olx/__init__.py#L169

after updating the olx website, the method of extracting the number from the offer has changed. Click and then retrieve the value.

I would like to use the BeautifulSoup auto for this.

Can anyone help me: How can I get to the phone number and download it?

Comment: BeautifulSoup is not able to interact with a website. All it does, is getting the html code for a given URL and then parsing it into an object, that is easy to work on. If you need to extract data, that is only available upon interacting with the website you need to use something like Selenium. Or you have to dig deeper into the code of the website, to see, if the information is somehow alraedy embedded in the document or dynamically loaded upon the button click.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a scraper using `scrapy_playwright`. The following steps are:

1. Click the accept on the cookies pop-up
2. Wait some time for the change to happen
3. Click on the 'show' button to unveil the phone number
4. wait some time for the change to happen
5. take a screenshot to confirm it happens
6. extract the telephone number.

You might want to check the official [github](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright) to learn - how to set up the tool in your settings.

Here's the script:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageCoroutine

class carnapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'button_click'
    start_urls = ["https://www.olx.pl/d/oferta/mieszkanie-do-wynajecia-40m2-ul-kosciuszki-96-CID3-IDNc5Bv.html#cc0c9f1b5c;promoted"]

    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url, 
                # headers=headers,
                callback = self.parse,
                meta = dict(
                    playwright = True,
                    playwright_page_coroutines = [
                        PageCoroutine("click", selector = "#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"),
                        PageCoroutine("wait_for_timeout", 5000),
                        PageCoroutine("click", selector = ".css-1af0qjn-BaseStyles"),
                        PageCoroutine("wait_for_timeout", 5000),
                        PageCoroutine("screenshot", path="test_button_show.png", full_page = True)
                    ]
                )
            )
    
    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'telephone':response.xpath("//li[@class='css-11hr49z-Text eu5v0x0']//a[@class='css-v1ndtc']//text()").get()
        }
```

Your expected output:

```
{'telephone': '793 855 805'}
```

If you get an error entering the site - try changing the user agent in the custom settings.